# "I'm starting to think..."

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

I'm aware that there are no continuous/progressive tenses in German, or at least no 1-to-1 equivalence.

I'm wondering, however, how I can idiomatically formulate the expression:

> I'm starting to think

obviously **not literally** that I am now beginning to think about something I previously wasn't, e.g. "*It's April and I'm [just now] starting to think about my taxes.*" I mean rather in the sense of starting to realize something (maybe that something is often slightly negative, unflattering, or casts us in a negative light? Can't think of any counterexamples at the moment.)

Example:

> I'm starting to think she doesn't really like me; she's just being nice so she can copy my homework

I looked in my go-to place LEO but its search didn't find any entries or forum discussions.

Thanks! :)

Comment: "obviously **not literally**" - at least in the example about guessing someone else's thoughts, I'd argue the expression *does* pretty literally say what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would translate your example as

> Allmählich habe ich den Verdacht, dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag

or

> Langsam habe ich das Gefühl, dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag

both transport the notion of becoming, i.e. the transition from one thought or feeling to the other.

You can use both 'Verdacht' and 'Gefühl' for 'thinking' here. You could even say

> Ich glaube langsam, dass sie mich gar nicht wirklich mag

Although i personally don't use 'glauben' or 'glaube' that much. But that's just me.

Comment: Excellent alternatives with *Gefühl* and *Verdacht*, thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome, @user19407. That's what we're here for

Answer (score 4):

A relatively common expression would be:

- Ich fange [langsam] an zu glauben, ... (dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag)

This is not much more than a rather literal translation of the English expression 'I'm [slowly] starting to think ...', but is also very common in German. The optional 'langsam' can be added to the expression if you want to emphasize that the realisation is only slowly emerging.

Comment: Würde ich im Kern auch als die naheliegendste Übersetzung ansehen, allerdings halte ich die verkürzte Form "Ich glaube langsam, ... (dass es sich soundso verhält)" für üblicher.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought about the option with *anfangen zu [Verb]* but for some reason this construction still feels a bit weird to me in general. I'm sure it's just that I haven't had enough exposure to it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Da gibt es einige Möglichkeiten:

> **Ich meine fast**, sie mag mich gar nicht wirklich, sondern sie tut bloß so nett, damit ich sie die Hausaufgaben abschreiben lasse.
>
> **Man möchte meinen**...
>
> **Mir schwant**...
>
> **Mir dämmert**...
>
> **Es kommt mir gerade so vor**...
>
> **Es scheint mir fast**...
>
> **Könnte es sein, dass** sie mich gar nicht wirklich mag, sondern bloß so nett tut, damit ich sie die Hausaufgaben abschreiben lasse?
>
> **Am Ende** mag sich mich gar nicht wirklich, sondern tut bloß so nett, damit ich sie die Hausaufgaben abschreiben lasse.

Alle diese Ausdrücke tragen ein Element des Aufkeimens einer Idee (*I am starting to think...*) in sich. Und, ach ja, auch möglich - wenn auch von der Sprachebene her fehl am Platz für eine Unterhaltung von Jugendlichen in der Schule - wäre

> **In mir keimt der Gedanke auf**...
>
> **Es drängt sich mir der Gedanke auf**...

Sehr altertümlich und heute nur noch ironisch einsetzbar sind:

> **Mich deucht**...
>
> **Mich dünkt**...

Zu guter Letzt könnte man natürlich auch ganz einfach sagen

> **Ich glaube**...

Das Element des Aufkeimens der Idee ist da zwar nur in Form des leichten Zweifels (*glauben* vs. *wissen*) drin, aber alltagspraktisch würde man das wohl einfach so ausdrücken.

Comment: Keine dieser Übersetzungen haben in sich, dass der Zweifel gerade am Entstehen ist.

Comment: Gesucht waren idiomatische Ausdrücke, also Ausdrücke, die von kompetenten Sprachnutzern verwendet werden und die bestimmte Inhaltselemente implizit (nicht explizit) enthalten. Überdies hat der Fragesteller eigens darauf hingewiesen, dass es ihm auf das *Beginnen* gar nicht eigentlich ankommt.

Comment: "Überdies hat der Fragesteller eigens darauf hingewiesen, dass es ihm auf das Beginnen gar nicht eigentlich ankommt." - Nein, das hat der Frageteller gerade nicht gemacht: "I mean rather in the sense of starting to realize something (maybe that something is often slightly negative, unflattering, or casts us in a negative light? Can't think of any counterexamples at the moment.)"

Comment: In meiner Welt sind *Ich meine fast...* und die anderen Ausdrücke durchaus gute idiomatische Indikatoren für einen Prozess, den man auch mit *I am starting to realize...* beschreiben kann. Allerdings natürlich losgelöst von allzu buchstäblicher Bedeutung.

Comment: Sehe ich überhaupt nicht so und es wäre interessant zu hören was andere dazu meinen. Höchstens vielleicht bei "Mir dämmert ...", allerdings ist das eine solch gehobene Sprache, dass es stilistisch meiner Meinung nach überhaupt nicht als Übersetzung in Frage kommt.

Answer (score 1):

We also use a starting *»So«* sometimes.

> - So langsam hab[e] ich das Gefühl, dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag.
> - So langsam macht sich das Gefühl in mir breit, dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag.
> - So langsam glaub[e] ich, dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag.
> - So langsam hab[e] ich den Eindruck, dass sie mich nicht wirklich mag.

*»So langsam«* means *»[allmählich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/allmaehlich)«* (gradually).